# Pandas Warning mesg

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

Can you please advise where my code is wrong. Why am I getting this error mesg-

```
Reliance ['long_position'] = np.nan
for x in range (len (Reliance)):
    if Reliance.Close[x] > Reliance.SMA20[x]:
        Reliance['long_position'][x] = 1
    if Reliance.Close[x] <= Reliance.SMA20[x]:
        Reliance['long_position'][x] = 0
```

I am calculating SMA20 and Close in other section of code.
**Warning:** A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See below picture for more details please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc9WJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is with the indexing. In pandas, you are supposed to use `loc` or `iloc` for indexing.

```
Reliance ['long_position'] = np.nan
for x in range (len (Reliance)):
    if Reliance.Close.iloc[x] > Reliance.SMA20.iloc[x]:
        Reliance['long_position'].iloc[x] = 1
    if Reliance.Close.iloc[x] <= Reliance.SMA20.iloc[x]:
        Reliance['long_position'].iloc[x] = 0
```

According to the documentation, the preferred way is as such:

```
Reliance.iloc[x, 'long_position'] = 0
```

[Pandas indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/indexing.html)

[Setting with copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)